# Deep Linking Google Maps URI

Tags: android, google-maps, deep-linking

I was developing an app that opens and shows Google Maps and shows nearby Waste Bins to a user. I would like to open up my app whenever user clicks on a map URI. I learnt it could be done using deep linking. 
My question is can I use Google Maps URI to open my app without violating any policy 
and if yes then which URI's should I link.

Comment: Are you referring to Google Maps APIs? or just the Google Maps(maps.google.com)?

Comment: @ShawnDomingo I am talking about just maps.google.com